# Why Does Date.parse gives 000 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```js
const newDate = Date.now()
const newDate2 = new Date(newDate)
const newDate3 = Date.parse(newDate2)

console.log(newDate);
console.log(newDate2);
console.log(newDate3);
```

Results:

`1638934575678`

`2021-12-08T03:36:15.678Z`

`1638934575000`

Why does it give 000 milliseconds when it should be 678?

Comment: do `Date.parse(newDate2.toISOString())`

Comment: `newDate2`'s string output doesn't contain milliseconds, _and it's that which is being passed to `Date.parse`_, not the ISO version listed in the question.

Comment: You have implicitly called `.toString()` and got what you requested.

Comment: It doesn't. As others have stated, you are attempting to parse a date object as if it was a string. This forces .toString() to get called on `newDate` and `newDate2` neither of which will include the milliseconds.

Comment: It's recommended to avoid `Date.parse()`. Why do you need to parse it anyway? Given that `newDate` already contains the value that you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.parse` - parse date from string. When you pass `newDate` parse method call .toString() from object and result will be output in format like this - `Wed Dec 08 2021 16:37:43 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`. As you can see - there is no milliseconds. According to this in your case `Date.parse` not gives it.
You can fix it by using constructor Date(your second example). Or you can use method toISOString() that return milliseconds.

```
Date.parse(new Date().toISOString());
```

Answer (score 1):

using method toISOString() worked for me to get the milliseconds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).